# Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 1 failed

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, centos6.5

I'm trying to do Port forwarding on my centOS machine. When i'm restarting iptables i'm getting the error `iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 1 failed [FAILED]`.

My iptables file is below

```
  Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
  # Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
  *filter
  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

  -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2181 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8020 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8032 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8088 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8440 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8441 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8887 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9933 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 19888 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 50070 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 50090 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 50470 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 60000 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 60010 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
  -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
  COMMIT
```

I'm unable to restart iptables. i'm using this command

```
service iptables start
```

(or)

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, unless you cut-and-pasted it wrong, that first line should also start with a comment.  That is, change

```
Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
```

to

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
```

You might want to pay closer attention to that second line, too; there's nothing wrong with it, but you should probably read it more.

Comment: Ashwanth, you accepted my answer, then un-accepted it and edited your question so the first line *is* commented-out.  Does that mean that you made a cut-and-paste error?  Does that mean you fixed the missing comment in your `iptables` file and the *line-1-failed* problem is gone?  Does that mean you fixed it and it *hasn't* gone?  Updating the question with no guide as to what else you're doing and what results you're getting isn't helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I commented first line. Now i can restart my iptables successfully but unable to open ports.

Comment: That is interesting, but it's a separate question - not least because your point (3) above says that you **can** open them.  I strongly recommend you write a separate question, in which you describe the new problem precisely - what you're trying to achieve, how you're doing it, what results you get - with evidence of a port not being opened, and give us the **running** ruleset (with `iptables -L -n -v`) as well as the config file.  I'm going to edit this question (and my answer) so it stands alone as a single, completed task, and watch with interest for your second question.